# new Instagram design

Tags: google-chrome, instagram

How do I turn on Dark Mode for *Instagram*? A friend's account on Google Chrome Windows pc

Can switch appearance
[image]
These are popular Instagram designs
But a friend created an account and found this new design rare and was not repeated. He tried to create other accounts that were all with the old designs
[image]
[image]